# How do I change the color of a li:active attribute for a data-filter?

Tags: html, css

How do I change the color of a li:active attribute for a data-filter?

I want the active filter to be red when selected. My code doesn't work, please help with a working solution. Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.portfolio-filter li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 46px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-filter li:hover {
  color: red;
}

.portfolio-filter li:active {
  color: red;
}

.portfolio-filter li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-section">
  <ul class="portfolio-filter controls text-center">
    <li class="control" data-filter="all">All</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".aerial">Aerial</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".corporate">Corporate</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".events">Events</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".outdoor">Outdoor</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".portraits">Portraits</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".studio">Studio</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How does the code work? There is no active class added to it?

Comment: Everything works, including li:hover. 

li;active turns red only when clicked on. I want it to stay red

Comment: It may work on your project but how can we see it and debug? :)

Comment: can you use JavaScript or should be done without?

Answer (score 0):

is that what you need?

```js
const portfolioFilter = document.querySelector('.portfolio-filter');
const controls = document.querySelectorAll('.control');

portfolioFilter.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const control = e.target.closest('.control');

  if (!control) return;

  controls.forEach((currentControl) => currentControl.classList.remove('active'));

  control.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.portfolio-section {
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.portfolio-filter {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 46px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.portfolio-filter li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 46px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-filter li:hover {
  color: red;
}

.portfolio-filter li:active {
  color: red;
}

.portfolio-filter li:current {
  color: red;
}

.portfolio-filter li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.portfolio-filter li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-section">
  <ul class="portfolio-filter controls text-center">
    <li class="control" data-filter="all">All</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".aerial">Aerial</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".corporate">Corporate</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".events">Events</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".outdoor">Outdoor</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".portraits">Portraits</li>
    <li class="control" data-filter=".studio">Studio</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. I copy/pasted the Javascript code and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @steezyza, this cannot be, it means that there is an error somewhere, update your question with the changed code